# Can you suggest an external microphone for a Canon EOS 7D with video recording?

Tags: dslr, video

I'm thinking about getting an external microphone for my Canon EOS 7D (since the built-in one isn't very good.) Nothing pro, but something that gives better audio quality. Suggestions?

Comment: As an accessory for a photographic camera, I don't consider this question to be off-topic.

Comment: It's not used for *actually taking photos* though, but for *making video*.  Just because you plug it into a DSLR with video mode doesn't make it any more on topic than if it plugs into a RED.

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself is: where do DSLR experts go? I think the answer will be: here. Since I'm looking for a camera accessory, I'll get more relevant answers here, not on a video forum. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the [Audio Technica Pro 24 CM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016ARZ9C). It has a nice short curled lead that fits snugly over the camera, a hot-shoe shock mount and I've gotten good results with it. It's not 'pro', it doesn't feature XLR but it's practical and reasonable.

Comment: Cool, it looks nice and the price isn't bad. I'll see if I can find it in shops here in Sweden.